# How to upload Images to online web server using VB.NET using desktop application

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I am developing a desktop application (network-aware) that work with network to collect and store the users' personal information, including **passports** and **signatures** of the users.

I initially store the images in database by converting them to **bytes** and store them in **longblub** data-type. Later after realizing that my database is getting to heavy decided to convert all the images back to normal **.jpg** file and upload them to web server.

Now as all the images are **manually** uploaded, i want make sure all the images of new users will be uploaded when **save-button** is click on the desktop application

Thank you.

Comment: Make your web server image folder shared on network, and give permission to all users read, write permission. When Save-button clicked, you can direct save all images the user uploaded into share folder.

Comment: Please give me more clue

Answer (score 0):

If you have the permission to create a shared folder on webserver \\servername\sharefolder$.
Use File Open Dialog Control, after button click, you can direct save file into the shared folder

```
string fulllocimage = openFileDialog1.FileName;
File.Copy(fulllocimage, Path.Combine(@"\\servername\sharefolder$",Path.GetFileName(fulllocimage));
```